# Excel cells randomly lost when uploading to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel, data

A similar question has been asked, and I've tried the solution, but to no avail.

Our stores have a spreadsheet, hosted on Sharepoint, that they add information to daily. Most stores simply keep it open and save when changes have been made, rather than going through the click > edit > save > close process every morning.

One of our stores has been randomly losing very specific cells of data. Always the same 8 days of data. The spreadsheet doesn't have any data validation checks. Major versions have been turned on. The timing has no rhyme or reason, as they've gone as little as an hour and as long as 3 days before those days are lost. I'm completely at a loss as to how I can remedy this. I'e watched the process and can confirm it's not a user error.

I've tried restarting the server, revoking and re-adding permissions, and saving the changes to the document myself.

Possibly useful information:

Sharepoint 2013

Excel Starter 2010

Store's local network is connected to ours via http tunnel

Server OS is Server 2k8 R2

Edit: [Similar Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88723/sharepoint-2007-users-losing-data-in-excel-files)

Comment: Will you add a link to the similar question? Is there a chance another store is overwriting or locking those cells somehow?

Comment: Link added. And no. I double checked the permissions, and only that store and any pertinent corporate staff have access. The only edit not made by them in the last month was made by me.

Comment: Are they editing in-browser? Or on a local copy of Excel? If it's local, changes will go through the "Upload Center". Maybe their file is getting cached there, and never pushed up to SharePoint.